# Hadoop Single-node vs Multi-node

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I am setup single node and multinode (1 master and 1 slave) cluster. When I try to run my application, it takes same time for both i.e. single node and multi-node. In my application, I am copying data from HDFS to local file system and then performing processing on it. Is this because I have files stored locally and the files are not accessible to other nodes in the cluster? I am providing a file which is actually divided into 3 chunks so logically it should be processed faster on multi-node.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to run my application, it takes same time for both i.e.
>   single node and multi-node.

Well the difference in time taken will vary depending on the type of operation performed and the amount of load generated by your application. For example, copying few MB's of data will take almost the same time on both single and multi-node cluster. Even, single node cluster might show up good results for small data set as compared to multi-node cluster. The actual power of Hadoop lies in processing of colossal volumes of data sets by utilizing multi-node clusters for parallel processing.

> In my application, I am copying data from HDFS to local file system
>   and then performing processing on it.

I do not see any sense in copying data on local file system for processing in a multi-node environment. In this way you are limiting yourself from using the power of distributed computing.